# Micronaut switching from 2.0.0.M3 to RC1: Gradle executes no tests anymore

Tags: gradle, micronaut

today I've switched from Micronaut 2.0.0.M3 to its RC1. After that Gradle does not execute test jobs anymore, reproducibly.

Output running M3:

```sh
$ cat gradle.properties 
micronautVersion=2.0.0.M3

$ ./gradlew clean build

> Configure project :
Executed by Gradle 6.5

> Task :compileJava
Note: Creating bean classes for 4 type elements

> Task :compileTestGroovy
[...]

> Task :test
[...]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 25s
14 actionable tasks: 14 executed

$ ls build/test-results/test/
binary
TEST-server.endpoint.ContributorControllerTest.xml
TEST-server.endpoint.PersonControllerTest.xml
```

With RC1:

```sh
$ cat gradle.properties 
micronautVersion=2.0.0.RC1

$ ./gradlew clean build

> Configure project :
Executed by Gradle 6.5

> Task :compileJava
Note: Creating bean classes for 4 type elements

[...]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 14s
14 actionable tasks: 14 executed

$ ls build/test-results/test/
binary

$ ls -s build/test-results/test/binary/
0 output.bin
4 output.bin.idx
0 results.bin
```

No XML files with test results are created; binary test output files are empty.
Very weird, indeed. Any idea what went wrong here?

Christian

---

Addition to answer comment from @saw303:
First I ran `clean build` again:

```sh
$ cat gradle.properties 
micronautVersion=2.0.0.RC1

$ ./gradlew clean build

> Configure project :
Executed by Gradle 6.5
- using Java 11.0.7
- using Groovy 2.5.11

> Task :compileJava
Note: Creating bean classes for 4 type elements

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 12s
14 actionable tasks: 14 executed
```

Now let's try it with task `test`:

```sh
$ ./gradlew test

> Configure project :
Executed by Gradle 6.5
- using Java 11.0.7
- using Groovy 2.5.11

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 658ms
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
```

Very short execution time, so no execution of any test cases!

```sh
$ ls build/test-results/test/
binary
```

Running `clean test`:

```sh
$ ./gradlew clean test

> Configure project :
Executed by Gradle 6.5
- using Java 11.0.7
- using Groovy 2.5.11

> Task :compileJava
Note: Creating bean classes for 4 type elements

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
```

Same result, not tests were executed:

```sh
$ ls build/test-results/test/
binary
```

Comment: what happens if you run `./gradlew test` manually?

Comment: Hi @saw303, added paragraph to answer your question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem.  Can you share a sample project which demonstrates the issue?  If yes, that would make it easier to identify what is wrong.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for your support. I've coined a temp GitLab access token (expires 2020-06-20) for read-only access to the repo. Master branch will be sufficient: `git clone https://stack-overflow@gitlab.com/denic-eg/dcmoeller/graph-db.git -b master` with `p2iAPD84ksfyWivepxPA`. Change to `server` subdir before launching `./gradlew clean build`.

Comment: Additional info: After clearing complete Gradle 3rd-party libs and Wrapper cache folder by running `rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/` I got the same result.

Comment: Micronaut 2.0.0.RC2 shows the same behaviour as RC1.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the build.gradle between 2.0.M3 and 2.0.RC1 changed slighly when it comes to declaring test dependencies.

In our projects we write tests in Spock.

Previous to RC1 the test dependencies have been declared such as:

```
    testAnnotationProcessor(platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    testAnnotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")
    testImplementation(platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
```

In RC1 the test dependencies are declared like:

```
    testImplementation(platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock")
```

At https://micronaut.io/launch/ you can play around with the latest version of Micronaut and preview the build.gradle. Hope this helps

Comment: I switched back and forth during project's history, that's true, but not my point: Simply change `M3` to `RC1` in `gradle.properties` and run `./gradlew test` again.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after fiddling around a lot with a freshly setup Micronaut environment (as recommended by @saw303) I've figured out that with my project the following code block in `build.gradle` is **required** to get tests executed when using Micronaut 2.0.0.RC1:

```
// use JUnit 5 platform
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When this block is **missing**, tests are compiled but **NOT** executed. With previous Micronaut 2.0.0.M3 this `useJUnitPlatform()` was **not** required, tests are executed without this addition.

Comment: Keep in mind that at the moment **all** tests are written using Groovy Spock test framework, **none** with JUnit.

Comment: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-test/issues/190

Comment: https://blog.solidsoft.pl/2020/01/02/migrating-spock-1.3-tests-to-spock-2.0/#gradle, especially "Update 20200218".